# Xamarin iOS System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm facing a weird issue in iOS 13.3 and 13.4 that having System.FormatException for some users only. The app is develop using Xamarin Forms. 
The error happen after calling to backend API to get user profile but before reaching the backend API (verified not reaching because AppInsights trace logs is not showing the call).

I have check the places where the error might be happening but have no clue.

**Exception Stack Trace recorded in AppCenter**

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Text            StringBuilder.FormatError ()
System.Text            StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args)
System                 String.FormatHelper (System.IFormatProvider provider, System.String format, System.ParamsArray args)
System                 String.Format (System.String format, System.Object[] args)
Mobile.Services        ApiService.GetAsync[T] (Wipro.MyBAT.Mobile.Core.Logging.AnalyticsEvent analyticsEvent, System.String endPoint, System.String queryString, System.Boolean requiresAuthentication, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancelToken, System.Boolean withRetry)
Mobile.Services        ApiService.GetUserProfile ()
Mobile.Services.Users  UserService.GetUserProfileFromServer ()
```

**Get User Profile method**

```
public async Task<Response<Common.Model.User>> GetUserProfile()
{
    var result = await GetAsync<Response<Common.Model.User>>(AnalyticsEvent.UserProfilePerformance, Endpoints.PROFILE).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result;
}
```

**Get User Profile method**

```
private async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(AnalyticsEvent analyticsEvent, string endPoint, string queryString = "", bool requiresAuthentication = true, CancellationToken cancelToken = default, bool withRetry = true)
            where T : new()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Throttler count", _throttler.CurrentCount.ToString() },
        { "Throttler limit", THROTTLER_LIMIT.ToString() },
        { "Retry", (!withRetry).ToString() }
    };

    await _throttler.WaitAsync();
    stopwatch.Start();
    string callId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    string url;
    string responseString = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        if (_connectivity.NetworkAccess == Xamarin.Essentials.NetworkAccess.None || _connectivity.NetworkAccess == Xamarin.Essentials.NetworkAccess.Unknown)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        url = $"{_environment.HostUrl}/api/{endPoint}{queryString}";
        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        if (requiresAuthentication)
        {
            var token = await _authService.GetAccessToken();
            message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
            message.Headers.Add("callid", callId);
        }

        // Error should be before this line as the call it not reaching API side
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(message, cancelToken);
```

Comment: This is a common error ,which maybe caused by lots of cases .For example ,  you defined int type in database and passing string value. Its basically datatype mismatch during the process. So you could firstly confirm if the type of parameters are correct .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the root cause of the problem. It is actually calling to the API server but is throwing exception before leaving mobile due to the user is having some VPN in the wifi network. Changing to use 4G instead of Wifi solve the problem.

The String.Format issue is due to the exception handling code using string.Format incorrectly. This makes the actual issue cover up by the string.format exception.

2 things learned:

- Always check first if using another network solve the problem or not
- Handle exception correctly

Comment: Don't forget to accept it , which will help more people :)